# RecyclerView Scrolling is Jittery

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The item layout of my recyclerView contains an ImageView and a couple of TextViews. The image is loaded from a BASE64 String. The base64 is loaded into the imageView using the Glide Library after converting it into a Byte Array.

I know that the jittery scrolling is caused because of the base 64, as I have tried loading a sample image from a url and the scrolling is smooth after that. But I have to use Base64 in my case as this is how the api I am using is.

I tried added the code for loading image from base64 inside a coroutine for better performance, But I don't see any improvement.

Code for Loading base64 into ImageView:

```
fun ImageView.loadBase64(base64String: String) {
    val bytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT)
    Glide.with(this.context)
        .load(bytes)
        .thumbnail(0.1f)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Drawable?>() {
            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Drawable,
                transition: Transition<in Drawable?>?
            ) {
                setImageDrawable(resource)
            }
        })
}
```

My onBindViewHolderView method

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        item ?: return
//        Glide.with(holder.itemView).load("https://st1.bgr.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Xiaomi-Mi-A3-Gadgets-2.jpg").into(holder.productIV)
        holder.productIV.loadBase64(item.picture)
        holder.priceTV.text = "$ ${item.price}"
        holder.titleTV.text = item.titleFormatted
        holder.productIV.transitionName = item.id.toString()
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(
                holder.productIV to item.id.toString()
            )
            it.findNavController().navigate(
                HomeFragmentDirections.actionStoreHomeToProductDetail(
                    item.id,
                    item.picture,
                    item.titleFormatted
                ), extras
            )
        }
    }
```

I just can't figure out how the scrolling can be made smooth, as the image has to be loaded in the onBindViewHolder method, and the image has to be in BASE64, but still I have to figure out a way to load the image fast enough so that the recycler view doesn't feel janky.

Comment: Instead of decoding Base64 string in the onBindViewHolder, Add an extra field to your item data class and populate it with decoded value while creating the objects and pass the field here.

Comment: @RaviKumar Thanks for the reply, I am trying the method you suggested. Just to confirm, did you mean adding a field of type "Drawable" inside the data class. If so, the conversion of the byte array to Drawable is an asynchronous operation. Adding items to list asynchronously is going to be a problem for me because i am using paging library.

Comment: No, Add a field bytes in your data class and store the decoded bytes in it. Then using glide load the image into the view.